# facing difficulty in creating my server through nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I am a beginner in Node js and Express and I was trying to create my server following this tutorial : https://codeforgeek.com/express-nodejs-tutorial/

This is my server.js code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("We have started our server on port 3000");
});
```

[error on cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iy7o.jpg)

Comment: I've posted a reply in the hope that it helps, but just give the version of express and node that you are using so we can try to replicate it with the same version please.

Comment: also, I'm trying to help as is, but note the section on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on not posting images of code/errors, it helps a lot if you post it directly as text in the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's the use of the ejs package without following the next steps of the tutorial, I get the same error at Step 3:

```
We have started our server on port 3000
/..stackhelp/59715144/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:119
  this._router.handle(req, res, function(err) {
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined
    at Function.app.handle (/Users/tamebadger/Projects/stackhelp/59715144/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:119:15)
    at Server.app (/Users/tamebadger/Projects/stackhelp/59715144/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:28:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:602:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:23)
```

Removing the ejs package would solve your problem if it was an option (you need it later in the tutorial)

Our of interest sake, see if you still get the issue if you add the next part of the tutorial:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send('Hello world');
});
```